# Exclude indexing of part of page in yahoo omnifind

Tags: search-engine

I'm using yahoo omnifind as search engine in a site. It is working fine except that I can not figure out how to exclude a certain part of a page. For example a tag cloud which is appearing on a lot of pages and therefore "pollutes" the search results. Any ideas?